# XSLT Grouping's : Add parent to set of elements in child elements

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

Using for-each-group I'm trying to add parent node by the class value of each para element. I tried to apply the grouping but the result is not good, I'm not getting the desired output. I'm confused about using the grouping in this case. Is there any better approach in this case for adding the parent node?

Current XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<section>
  <h1>Some heading</h1>
  <section>
   <p>normal paragaraph</p>
   <p class="list">list 1</p>
   <p class="list">list 1</p>
  
    <p>normal paragaraph</p>
   <p class="list">list 2</p>
   <p class="list">list 2</p>
  </section>
    <section> ...  </section>
</section>
```

XSLT used:

```
   <xsl:template match="section">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-by="if (@class='list') then 'list' else 'nolist'">
        <xsl:for-each select="current-grouping-key()">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() = 'list'">
              <list>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
              </list>                
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
```

Current Output:

```
<h1>Some heading</h1>
<p>normal paragaraph</p>
<p>normal paragaraph</p>
<list>
   <p class="list">list 1</p>
   <p class="list">list 1</p>
   <p class="list">list 2</p>
   <p class="list">list 2</p>
</list>

<p>normal paragaraph</p>
....
```

Expected Output:

```
<section>
  <h1>Some heading</h1>
  <section>
   <p>normal paragaraph</p>
   <list>
      <p class="list">list 1</p>
      <p class="list">list 1</p>
   </list>
    <p>normal paragaraph</p>
   <list>
      <p class="list">list 2</p>
      <p class="list">list 2</p>
   </list>
</section>
<section>...</section>
</section>
```

Comment: Look at existing `group-adjacent` examples [tag:xslt-grouping]

Comment: :) yep this helped, thank you for showing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="section">
  <section>
    <h1>Some Heading</h1>
    <section>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="section/p" group-by=".">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() != 'normal paragaraph'">
                <p>normal paragaraph</p>
                <list>
                  <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                      <p class="list"><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></p>
                  </xsl:for-each>
                </list>
              </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </section>
  </section>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I hope my contribution will be helpful for someone

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I hope this helps someone, as commented by @marthin honnen, I tried with group-adjacent, got the desired output, this helped.

```
 <xsl:template match="section">
     <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="if (@class='list') then 'list' else 'nolist'">
        <xsl:for-each select="current-grouping-key()">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() = 'list'">
              <list>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
              </list>                
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Consider dropping the `<xsl:for-each select="current-grouping-key()">`, that has no point as the `current-grouping-key` (in XSLT 2 or in XSLT 3 with the default composite="no" key behaviour) is a single value. So you just need the `xsl:choose/xsl:when`.